# SAS counter for a sequence of numbers

Tags: sas, counter

I am struggling with the following. I wish to create a counter for a given sequence of "ones". For instance, I have the following:
`1

1

1

1

0

0

1

1

1

0

0

1

1

1

1`

Given that sequence, I wish to have a counter for each sequence of `1` until I hit a `0`. This is what I want:

`1 1

1  1

1  1

1  1

0  .

0  .

1  2

1  2

1  2

0  .

0  .

1  3

1  3

1  3

1  3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
data have;
input x;
datalines;
0
1
0
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
1
1
;
run;

data want(keep= x z);
set have;
retain y;
retain u;

if _N_ eq 1 then do; 
    y = x;
    u = 1;
end;

if x eq 1 then z = u;
else if x eq 0 and x ne y then u = u + 1;
y = x;
run;
```

`y` keeps track of the previous value of `x`, `u` keeps the count. When `x` equals 1 then `u` is stored in `z`. When `x` equals 0 and previous value of `x` was not 0, then increase the value of `u` by 1.

Result:

```
x    z
------
0    .
1    1
0    .
1    2
1    2
1    2
1    2
0    .
0    .
1    3
1    3
1    3
0    .
0    .
1    4
1    4
1    4
1    4
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the data in dperetin's example, alternative solution using 'notsorted' :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by x notsorted ;
  if x = 1 then do ;
    if first.x then y + 1 ;
    z = y ;
  end ;
run ;
```